# How would I add JSON to my classpath for a project? Using VS Code

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code, installation

I'm trying to use JSON.simple version 1.1.1 for my project (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1) and have my dependancies set up in my pom.xml file, but can't figure out how to add the jar file to my classpath (I'm assuming this is the issue I'm getting, but this is my absolute first time working with JSON so maybe I'm way off).

I'm sshing into my school's server using VS code & a VPN if that makes a difference.

Would anyone be able to offer any help?

Comment: Your maven project should download the jar defined in your pom file. That's one of the maven project porpouse. I never coded Java using VS-Code or maven project, you should use IntelliJ it has features which will download automaticly your pom dependencies.

Comment: You're right, my problem was elsewhere & my pom file already had it downloaded! I have to use VS code at my prof's request, IntelliJ is my IDE of choice too :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project

Open the view
Java Dependencies

Drill down and find the tree node for Referenced Libraries.

Click on it or hover over it.  There should be a '+' plus sign.  Click on the plus sign and navigate the file selection dialog to your jar file.  Select the jar file in the dialog and then click the button "Select jar files".

Afterwards, the jar file will show as a node underneath Referenced Libraries.